# How to get scroll bar to appear to right of listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox and a scroll bar but the scroll bar appears and the right side of the window instead of to the right of the listbox. How to put scroll bar to just right of the listbox?

```
def viewrooms():
    rooms = Toplevel()
    rooms.title('Room List')
    rooms.geometry("1200x600+350+50")

    roomlb = Listbox(rooms, height=25, width=90, font="12")
    roomlb.place(x=200, y=50)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(rooms, orient="vertical")
    scrollbar.config(command=roomlb.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    roomlb.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to just right of the listbox"? Your listbox is appearing perfectly at the right, unless you move the listbox.

Comment: I want the scrollbar to appear right beside of the listbox. Instead, it appears to the right of the entire window.

Comment: Ok, I see. But my question is the right of the listbox is at the very right of the window.

Comment: No. The listbox is centered to the window.

Comment: When I run the program, it is at the right of the window.

Comment: But I think I know the answer to your question.

Comment: ***scroll bar appears ... to the right of the listbox***: Use a `Frame`, to group the `Listbox` and `Scrollbar`

Comment: @stovfl That is what I am attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Frame to group your widgets Frame and Listbox.
Your code should look like:

```
frame = Frame(rooms)
frame.place(x=200, y=50)

roomlb = Listbox(frame, height=25, width=90, font="12")
roomlb.pack(side="left", fill="y")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.config(command=roomlb.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
roomlb.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Comment: Ok. Thank You for your input!